# Интерполяционный многочлен Лагранжа С++

Tags: c++

Требовалось написать код для интерполирование функции многочленом Лагранжа. Написал код используя массивы. Тоесть,  узлы, значения в узлах, базисные полиномы в конкретно заданной точке загоняя в массив.  Преподаватель не принял, ибо ему надо без массивов. Не могу понять как это можно реализовать. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Возможно он просто правоверный приверженец C++, и его слова следует понимать, что вместо массивов должны быть вектора (vector, первоначально из stl)

Comment: а может ему нужны переменные `a1`, `a1` .. `an`. Всякие бывают преподаватели.

Comment: я почему-то больше склоняюсь ко второму варианту - гораздо чаще приходилось видеть преподов, которым какие-то неведомые религиозные причины запрещали пользоваться теми или иными средствами языка, нежели тех, кто умел бы пользоваться языком более-менее полно. И не дай бог при таком преподе написать std::string вместо char* - студент тут же предавался анафеме как последний еретик